# HTML/CSS grid layout text elements position

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I got a codepen I've been working on but cant seem to get the quote to correctly position one below the other.
As you can see here the author gets placed to the side in the same grid cell.
https://codepen.io/AngelCasas/pen/qXdGbd?editors=1100
html5:

```
    <blockquote class="phrase">
      <p style="font-size: 3vh">"The monotony and solitude of a quiet life<br> stimulates the creative mind"</p>
      <p>- Albert Einstein -</p>
    </blockquote><!-- End of quote -->
```

CSS:

```
    .phrase {
      grid-area: phrase;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Cardo, serif, Arial;
      font-size: 1.5vh;
      color: #00264d;
      }
```

Is there any way I can get the text to flow down instead of sideways?
Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Looking at the codepen, I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Would you mind expanding your description of the problem?  What does this mean ...
`Is there any way I can get the text to flow down instead of sideways?`

Comment: Sorry I updated the codepen and resolved the issue with the first answer but thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `display: flex;` from the css and the next `<p>` will be placed below the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Add the property 'flex-direction' and set it to column:

```
.phrase {
      grid-area: phrase;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Cardo, serif, Arial;
      font-size: 1.5vh;
      color: #00264d;
      flex-direction: column;
}
```